# previous 10 tr jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$('.dynamicsubtotal').each(function() {
  $(this).prev('.value').css('color', 'red')
  market += parseInt($(this).prev('.value').find('td:nth-child(6)').text());
  console.log(market)
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='dynamicsubtotal'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='dynamicsubtotal'></tr>
</table>
```

I want to select all the 10 tr with **class value**  prior to tr with **class dynamicsubtotal**

Comment: i don't really get what you want to do...how can somebody "select" a `<tr>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are really trying to do is to find all the `value` elements before each `dynamicsubtotal` element, so you are looking for [prevUntil](https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)

```js
$('.dynamicsubtotal').each(function(i) {
  $(this).prevUntil('.dynamicsubtotal', '.value').css('color', 'red').append('<td>' + i + '</td>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='dynamicsubtotal'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='value'></tr>
  <tr class='dynamicsubtotal'></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if there are more than 10 elements and OP want to select only previous 10 elements? FYI, that is not my downvote.

Comment: @Tushar please read the Question: *`I want to select all the 10 tr with class value prior to tr with class dynamicsubtotal`* so Arun's answer is quite good IMO

Comment: @Tushar why did you delete the answer i was about to try the answer to my code :(

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what i want is for every tr with class dynamicsubtotal  there will be previous 10 tr with class value i hope i make sense :)

Comment: @BrownmanRevival I think you are saying about 10 records because you know that between each dynamicsubtotal there will 10 value elements

Comment: But as a logical component, you want to add add all `value` element's value to get the value for the `subtotal` that will be more logical approach I think...

Comment: @BrownmanRevival Assume there is a case where the last `dynamicsubtotal` don't have 10 `value` elements then going by the count can mess up the result

Comment: yes you are right that is what i want to do i want to add every 10 value to get the sub total. in the end i will get all the subtotal and get the grand total. So this is the approach? Im sorry about the down vote though

Comment: I see so what i must do is go with the class name get all the class value prior to subtotal and add them that seems the right way to do it :)\

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/

```
$('.dynamicsubtotal').each(function() {

  var market = 0;
  var $prevTRS = $(this).prevUntil('.dynamicsubtotal', '.value');

  $prevTRS.each(function() {
     market += parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(6)').text() || 0, 10);
  });

  console.log(market);
});
```

Example (using `nth-child(1)` for HTML simplicity)

```js
$('.dynamicsubtotal').each(function() {

  var market = 0;
  var $prevTRS = $(this).prevUntil('.dynamicsubtotal', '.value');

  $prevTRS.each(function() {
    market += parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text() || 0, 10);
  });

  console.log(market);
});
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr class='dynamicsubtotal'><td>dyn</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='value'><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr class='dynamicsubtotal'><td>dyn</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should know with your rep to post ***complete*** answers...not placeholders. No need to be the FGITW.

Comment: can you explain you answer a bit i cant understand this part `var $prevTRS = $(this).prevUntil('.dynamicsubtotal', '.value');`

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong from dynamicsubtotal to value? i want from dynamicsubtotal and all prev('.value')

Comment: @BrownmanRevival https://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/ says it all, the first parameter `'.dynamicsubtotal'` is the **until**, while the second parameter  `'.value'` just makes sure to target all the `.value` TRs